# GCC error while using code blocks for const unsigned long

Tags: c++, gcc

Consider this code

```
class Reflect : public flemax::annotation::XAnnotation {
  public:
    Reflect(const unsigned long id, const std::string& home, const char type, const std::string& name = "me", const int value = 4, const bool valid = false, const signed char gender = 'M') : id_(id), home_(home), type_(type), name_(name), value_(value), valid_(valid), gender_(gender){} 
    ~Reflect() {}

    const unsigned long id() { return id_; }
    const std::string& home() { return home_; }
    const char type() { return type_; }
    const std::string& name() { return name_; }
    const int value() { return value_; }
    const bool valid() { return valid_; }
    const signed char gender() { return gender_; }

  private:
    const unsigned long id_;
    const std::string home_;
    const char type_;
    const std::string name_;
    const int value_;
    const bool valid_;
    const signed char gender_;

}; // class Reflect
```

it does not compile and the compiler gives me this weird error.

```
||=== flemax_base, DebugAnnotator ===|
/programming/cpp-projects/flemax/flemax_base/base/xannottest.cc|21|error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘long’|
/programming/cpp-projects/flemax/flemax_base/base/xannottest.cc|24|error: expected ‘;’ before ‘long’|
/programming/cpp-projects/flemax/flemax_base/base/xannottest.cc|25|error: expected ‘;’ before ‘const’|
/programming/cpp-projects/flemax/flemax_base/base/xannottest.cc|33|error: expected ‘;’ before ‘long’|
/programming/cpp-projects/flemax/flemax_base/base/xannottest.cc||In constructor ‘flemax::test::Reflect::Reflect(int)’:|
/programming/cpp-projects/flemax/flemax_base/base/xannottest.cc|21|error: class ‘flemax::test::Reflect’ does not have any field named ‘id_’|
/programming/cpp-projects/flemax/flemax_base/base/xannottest.cc|21|error: ‘id’ was not declared in this scope|
/programming/cpp-projects/flemax/flemax_base/base/xannottest.cc|21|error: argument of type ‘const int (flemax::test::Reflect::)()’ does not match ‘const int’|
/programming/cpp-projects/flemax/flemax_base/base/xannottest.cc|21|error: argument of type ‘const bool (flemax::test::Reflect::)()’ does not match ‘const bool’|
/programming/cpp-projects/flemax/flemax_base/base/xannottest.cc|21|error: argument of type ‘const signed char (flemax::test::Reflect::)()’ does not match ‘const signed char’|
||=== Build finished: 12 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

when i remove the unsigned modifier, everything works fine. 
Probably i have been coding for the last 24 hours so i dont see whats wrong, and am struck.
I dont want to sleep until that code compiles the way it is.

am using codeblocks on ubuntu and gcc 4.4.3

Thanks men

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would bet that you have a `#define unsigned WHATEVER` somewhere. Or maybe you are compiling with `-Dunsigned=WHATEVER`.

So the compiler sees `const WHATEVER long x` everywhere, and the `long` type makes no sense there.

Comment: To be frank such a thought didnt cross my mind at all as a bug. Thanks!!

Comment: What I wonder now is how did that macro get defined in the first place.

Comment: The code was being generated, so i could not tell what type of macro was being defined for the type. It was a test for generated code to see if it compiles

Answer (score 0):

This code compile on my computer, using gcc 4.6.3 . The solution is to change compiler version to the latest.

But, it is a strange error, probably there is a compiler bug. If You don't want to change your compiler version, try putting private section at the begin of class. Hope that help.

Comment: "Compilator"? Surely you mean "compiler".

Comment: Changing to have private section first does not help, neither does updating to gcc/g++ 4.6.2